how to run a docker image in windows machine
I have to build and android application using docker image in a windows machine using command lines , without opting with docker desktop or virtual machine , just I need to use my local windows machine to run it
I tried to use docker diamon to be able to make the container up running using those commands :
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers –All
dockerd -H tcp://localhost:2376 --data-root D:\ProgramData\docker

And they works fine without any issue
And then I tried to run a the docker file to be able to download the required image and build this image into this container ,
docker build --file "D:\Dockerization\build-apex.Dockerfile" --build-arg BASE_DIR=. . -t app- 
build:latest
Sending build context to Docker daemon   3.33GB
Step 1/18 : FROM openjdk:11-jdk
 ---> c18b9b54de01
Step 2/18 : ARG BASE_DIR
---> Using cache
---> fdd7eaf533b1
Step 3/18 : RUN apt-get update
---> Running in f4952a55c7f5
apt-get : The term 'apt-get' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:76
+ ... ce = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; apt-get update
+                                                            ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (apt-get:String) [], ParentConta
insErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 
'SilentlyContinue'; apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 1

this is my docker file
FROM openjdk:11-jdk

ARG BASE_DIR
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl unzip
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-distutils
RUN apt-get install -y xsltproc
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && \
python3 get-pip.py && \
rm get-pip.py

ENV ANDROID_HOME /opt/android-sdk-linux
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform- 
tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin

# Download and install Android SDK
RUN mkdir -p ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools && \
cd ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools && \
curl -o sdk-tools.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux- 
6858069_latest.zip && \
unzip sdk-tools.zip && \
mv cmdline-tools latest && \
rm sdk-tools.zip

# Accept Android SDK licenses
RUN yes | sdkmanager --licenses

# Install necessary Android SDK components
RUN sdkmanager "platforms;android-29" "build-tools;29.0.3"

Normally  openjdk:11-jdk image has a linux container , so if I need to use it , I will be able to run linux commands
So why I have got this issue and what is the solution to resolve this problem

Hi, without some kind of virtualization you can not because how docker works and use host properties. Please refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers
Base rule is if you want build linux container you have to build it on linux :)

If you look at the OpenJDK 11-jdk tag on Docker Hub, you can see that there are both Windows and Linux versions of that image available. Since you're using Windows Docker, it pulls the Windows version and that doesn't have apt-get installed. Apt is the Debian package manager. If you want to run Linux containers you need to use WSL2 and run Docker there. That runs a Linux VM for you under the covers.

Could you please give me the detailed steps to run linux container on my machine
